Spring Boot 3.4: @MockitoSpyBean causes NullPointerException during @PostConstruct
I'm currently migrating a Spring Boot app to version 3.4.
In this version, @MockBean and @SpyBean are deprecated and replaced by @MockitoBean and @MockitoSpyBean
I've made the changes in my class annotated with @TestConfiguration, and since then my SpringBootTests are failing at the initialization phase.
This is how my configuration class looks like:
@TestConfiguration
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @MockitoSpyBean
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    void setUp() {
        when(languageRepository.findAllCodes()).thenReturn(List.of("fr", "en"));
    }
}

This configuration is included via a custom meta-annotation, like this:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {IntegrationTestConfig.class, SpringSecurityTestConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:sql/clearTables.sql", executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public @interface IntegrationTest {

}

Since making this change, I now encounter the following error during @PostConstruct execution:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "package.whatever.LanguageRepository.findAllCodes()" because "this.languageRepository" is null
The error does not occur if I revert to the deprecated API (@SpyBean). Everything works fine with the old annotations.
My questions:

What am I missing here?
How can I recover the same behavior as before, preferably without relying on base test class inheritance with a @BeforeEach setup?


Edit: Giving context
This @SpyBean is used to mock something only done at application startup where an external WS call is made.
@Bean
ApplicationRunner fetchTranslations(LocalazyService translationService) {
    log.info("Initializing translations...");
    return ignored -> translationService.updateTranslationsWithCdn();
}


@PostConstruct on a test seems unusual - try @BeforeEach?

I guess it was inspired by this post: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-configure-mockbean-components-before-application-start#4-using-mockbean-in-an-external-test-configuration-class
I'm really trying to avoid inheritance base class because it would be a lot of changes in the code base, but maybe I'll have no other choice.

It looks like that @MockitoSpyBean requires that you have a bean present that Mockito would be able to spy on. Previously, with @SpyBean bean was created if none was present.
I use @MockitoBean(answers = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS) instead of @SpyBean. Alternatively, you can make sure that you actually create a bean yourself in a test configuration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/annotations/integration-spring/annotation-mockitobean.html

I have tried your solution, using @MockitoBean(answers = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS) but I'm still having the NullPointerException in the PostConstruct.

I suppose you should not use @PostConstruct annotation in a test. Instead use @BeforeEach  (junit 5) or @Before (junit4)

Well, it's not the test itself that has the @PostConstruct but the @TestConfiguration. Since the configuration is shared accross multiple tests, it allowed me to have the same test context cached accross all of my suite.
Using @BeforeEach for the same behavior means I'll have to resort to inheritance.

Would that even work if you have more than one @Test method? Because  in contrast to @BeforeEach  - @PostConstruct method will be executed once - when bean is created (assuming that Spring Context is not re-created for each test. Therefore on second and other tests mock will not be initialized?

I'm not sure about that. Probably. My use case is that this mocking is done once at the application startup, because an external WS call is done to retrieve translations for the app. After that, the mock is not used anymore in any of my tests. It's really a mock only for the initialization, not for the tests themselves.

In our project, we encountered an issue with @MockBean and resolved it as follows:
We had the following setup in a @TestConfiguration class:
@TestConfiguration
public class FeatureApiTestConfiguration {
    @MockBean(name = "featureServerSideEventStreamWebClient")
    private WebClient featureServerSideEventStreamWebClient;

    @MockBean
    private FeatureApiSSEClient featureApiSSEClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        Mockito.when(featureApiSSEClient.streamEventsForFeatures(Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(Flux.empty());
    }

}

To resolve the issue, we removed this configuration entirely and replaced it by moving the mocked beans to our BaseIT class. Here's how we updated the implementation:
BaseIT.class:
@MockitoBean(name = "featureServerSideEventStreamWebClient")
private WebClient featureServerSideEventStreamWebClient;

@MockitoBean(answers = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)
private FeatureApiSSEClient featureApiSSEClient;

We also removed the @PostConstruct method since it was no longer needed. With this setup, our tests worked as expected with RETURNS_MOCKS.
This topic has been further discussed in the Spring Boot community and relates to the recent deprecation of @MockBean and @SpyBean. You can find more details in the Spring Boot 3.4 Release Notes.
Here is the disccusion: Discussion

Interesting. I didn't know there were discussions about this issue. Thanks for pointing it out. So in the end, you replaced your setup by using inheritance if I understand this right. Because of this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33934

Yes sir, the issue which caused it to not work with the @Configuration. However, the problem persisted when I move to BaseIT. When I used Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS, my issue was resolved.
